# como configuro el "cancel" y el "x" de showInputDialog?

Tags: java, java-swing, try-catch

Empiezo diciendo que soy muy nuevo en Java y sería de gran ayuda y estaré muy agradecido por algún consejo, el programa funciona normal pero el problema que tengo es que cuando le doy click al "x" no se cierra en vez de eso el programa se repite una y otra vez, además cuando le doy click al "cancel" no logro hacer que el programa se termine.

NOTA: El try catch lo usé para que no permita el ingreso de letras.

EJEMPLO DE MI CODIGO

```
introducir el código aquí

    String pregunta;
    int ban = 0;
    Double lados;
    do
    {           
        try
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"PROGRAMA QUE INTRODUCE UN NÚMERO");
            
        pregunta = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE LADOS DE LA PIRÁMIDE (DEBE SER MAYOR A 2)");
        lados=(double) Integer.parseInt(pregunta);
        
                    
        
        } catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INGRESE SOLO NÚMEROS POR FAVOR"); ban = 1;}
    
    } while(ban!= 0);
```

DE ANTEMANO MUCHAS GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA Y POR SU TIEMPO

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Generalmente se usa `showConfirmDialog` para poder recuperar las respuestas del tipo `YES`, `NO`, `CANCEL`, pero yo veo que estás usando `showMessageDialog`

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, mira yo me refiero a que cuando trato de cerrar el showMessageDialog (con el "x") o showInputDialog (con el "cancel" o "x") no se cierran o le dan termino al programa sino que se ejecuta una y otra vez por accion del try catch, mi pregunta es como hacer para cerrarlo sin dejar de usar el try catch

Comment: El bucle se repite mientras `ban` no sea igual a cero: `while(ban!= 0);` entonces puedes poner esto: `ban=0;` y el bucle terminará.